# How to call a RESTful web service from Android?

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, authorization

I have written a REST web service in Netbean IDE using Jersey Framework and Java.

For every request the user needs to provide a username and a password, I know that this authentication is not a best practice (using a curl command like: `curl -u username:password -X PUT http://localhsot:8080/user`).

Now I want to call a REST web service from an Android Class.

How should I do it?

I have an Android Class which uses `DefaultHttpClient` and `CredentialUsernameAndPassword`, but when I run it in Eclipse, sometimes I get a runtime exception or SDK exception.

Answer (score 19):

This is an sample restclient class

```
public class RestClient
{
    public enum RequestMethod
    {
        GET,
        POST
    }
    public int responseCode=0;
    public String message;
    public String response;
    public void Execute(RequestMethod method,String url,ArrayList<NameValuePair> headers,ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) throws Exception
    {
        switch (method)
        {
            case GET:
            {
                // add parameters
                String combinedParams = "";
                if (params!=null)
                {
                    combinedParams += "?";
                    for (NameValuePair p : params)
                    {
                        String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");
                        if (combinedParams.length() > 1)
                            combinedParams += "&" + paramString;
                        else
                            combinedParams += paramString;
                    }
                }
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);
                // add headers
                if (headers!=null)
                {
                    headers=addCommonHeaderField(headers);
                    for (NameValuePair h : headers)
                        request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }
                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
            case POST:
            {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                // add headers
                if (headers!=null)
                {
                    headers=addCommonHeaderField(headers);
                    for (NameValuePair h : headers)
                        request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }
                if (params!=null)
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> addCommonHeaderField(ArrayList<NameValuePair> _header)
    {
        _header.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        return _header;
    }
    private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        try
        {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null)
            {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                response = convertStreamToString(instream);
                instream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a class's source code without comments or summarizing what is happening at which point is confusing to someone new to RESTful services such as myself.

Answer (score 14):

Recently discovered that a third party library - [Square Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) can do the job very well.

---

Defining REST endpoint

```
public interface GitHubService {
   @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
   List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user,Callback<List<User>> cb);
}
```

---

Getting the concrete service

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .build();
GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);
```

---

Calling the REST endpoint

```
List<Repo> repos = service.listRepos("octocat",new Callback<List<User>>() { 
    @Override
    public void failure(final RetrofitError error) {
        android.util.Log.i("example", "Error, body: " + error.getBody().toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void success(List<User> users, Response response) {
        // Do something with the List of Users object returned
        // you may populate your adapter here
    }
});
```

---

The library handles the json serialization and deserailization for you. You may customize the serialization and deserialization too.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter())
    .create();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .build();
```

Comment: is there any real example about this? i don't quite understand in detail.

Comment: Retrofit generates the Restful web services clients for you. You just need to define interfaces with some annotations. For details, see http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I already look at it. But o still dont get it. Trats why im looking for an real example. No just a few pieces of code

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/github-client/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/GitHubClient.java

Comment: I have been using Retrofit for a few months and have never had better success with a Java library in my life. I recommend using [Google's Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) with it, as it makes JSON (de)serialization really really easy.

Answer (score 6):

Stop with whatever you were doing ! :)

Implement the **RESTful client as a SERVICE** and delegate the intensive network stuff to activity independent component: a SERVICE.

Watch this insightful video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE where Virgil Dobjanschi is explaining his approach(es) to this challenge...

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring for Android with RestTemplate 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/

```
// The connection URL 
String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/" + 
    "services/search/web?v=1.0&q={query}";

// Create a new RestTemplate instance
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Add the String message converter
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

// Make the HTTP GET request, marshaling the response to a String
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "Android");
```

Comment: Those who down-voted should explain what is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used `OkHttpClient` to call restful web service. It's very simple.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
String body = response.body().string()
```

Comment: That's not a _built-in_ component of Android.

Answer (score 0):

What back-end? If JAVA then you can use REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey.

On the Android side you can use this simple RestClient to work with that REST service.

For JSON <--> Object mapping on both sides (Android, Java back-end) you can use GSON.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps am late or maybe you've already used it before but there is another one called [ksoap](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/) and its pretty amazing.. It also includes timeouts and can parse any SOAP based webservice efficiently. I also made a few changes to suit my parsing.. Look it up

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to consume RestFul in android.

**Step1**

Create a android blank project.

**Step2**

Need internet access permission. write the below code in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
```

**Step3**

Need RestFul url which is running in another server or same machine.

**Step4**

Make a RestFul Client which will extends AsyncTask. See RestFulPost.java.

**Step5**

Make DTO class for RestFull Request  and Response.

**RestFulPost.java**

```
package javaant.com.consuming_restful.restclient;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import java.util.Map;
import javaant.com.consuming_restful.util.Util;
/**
 * Created by Nirmal Dhara on 29-10-2015.
 */
public class RestFulPost extends AsyncTask<map, void,="" string=""> {
    RestFulResult restFulResult = null;
    ProgressDialog Asycdialog;
    String msg;
    String task;
    public RestFulPost(RestFulResult restFulResult, Context context, String msg,String task) {
        this.restFulResult = restFulResult;
        this.task=task;
        this.msg = msg;
        Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Map... params) {
        String responseStr = null;
        Object dataMap = null;
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(params[0].get("url").toString());

        try {
            dataMap = (Object) params[0].get("data");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Log.d("data  map", "data map------" + gson.toJson(dataMap));
            httpost.setEntity(new StringEntity(gson.toJson(dataMap)));
            httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient= Util.getClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.d("resonse code", "----------------" + statusCode);

            if (statusCode == 200)
                responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                responseStr = "{\n" +
                        "\"status\":\"fail\",\n" +
                        " \"data\":{\n" +
                        "\"ValidUser\":\"Service not available\",\n" +
                        "\"code\":\"404\"\n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "}";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseStr;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Asycdialog.setMessage(msg);
        //show dialog
        Asycdialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Asycdialog.dismiss();
        restFulResult.onResfulResponse(s,task);
    }
}
```

For more details and complete code please visit http://javaant.com/consume-a-restful-webservice-in-android/#.VwzbipN96Hs

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Library That I have created for simple Webservice Calling,

You can use this by adding a one line gradle dependency -

```
compile 'com.scantity.ScHttpLibrary:ScHttpLibrary:1.0.0'
```

Here is the demonstration of using.

https://github.com/vishalchhodwani1992/httpLibrary