# Long mathematical computations in android app

Tags: android, algorithm, computation

I'm an amateur developer and I'm creating an Android app that will perform long mathematical calculation (involving multiple for-loops for example). I've read on the Android Developer website that Renderscript is a possible way of reducing computational time and memory. However, I have no readability (or writability for that matter) in C, so I was wondering if there's any more effective (time/memory) ways of carrying out the computations.

Otherwise, if there's really no other ways, are there helpful resources for me to look besides the Renderscript section on the Android website?

Comment: you can use AsyncTask or Thread

Comment: What about doing the computations on a server and sending back the results to the Android device?

Comment: Android terminals are not usually adapted to long computations because of limited energy supply. A server-based solution seems more adapted, and more scalable by using distributed architectures.

Comment: Would the Google AppEngine be a feasible option as the server for doing the computations? If so, what's the mechanism for sending and receiving data from AppEngine in the Android device?

Comment: Renderscript was deprecated in jelly bean

Comment: Is it possible that you are only assuming that it will be slow and memory intensive? Have you tried anything? Remember that communicating with a server also uses energy, takes time and may fail. You should only consider the server option if you are sure that computing on Android is the worse option.

Comment: @RaghavSood Renderscript isn't deprecated. Only graphical part which duplicated OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices to compute directly on device:

[Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html):

- (+) Supports different types of current and future architectures.
- (+) It will enable computations on GPU in future.
- (+) It is easily scalable to run on multiple cores.
- (-) Minimal API level 11.

[Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html):

- (+) cross-platform code
- (-) Application have to be compiled for each available architecture by developer.
- (-) If new architecture emerge then new build is needed.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing the computations on a server and sending back the results to the Android device?

You can implement a RESTful service server side and [call it via http from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047194/how-to-call-restful-web-service-from-android).