# How implement RESTFUL services in Android?

Tags: android, database, rest

I want to ask you a question about REST web service and Android.
I want to make an application which communicates with a remote database and display the values in a listview. Now, the problem at the moment is how to communicate with a remote database: I've read about REST services and I've understand they are necessary if you want to communicate with a db in a safe way, but I don't know how to make it really.
My idea of this application is: I connect to a .php page placed in a remote server (using a free domain) and there i create the query to the database, so:

ANDROID APPLICATION -----> PHP FILE ----> REMOTE DATABASE

The question are:

- Where do I implement REST services?
- Is my idea right? Or should I change something?
- Does someone have a snippet or tutorial about this problem or generally about REST services? I've searched on the net but I haven't found anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First result in Google:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/1076

It has a code example of fetching data from Android via an exposed web resource.

Also other SO Qs about this, for example: [How to call a RESTful web service from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047194/how-to-call-restful-web-service-from-android)

Did you really search that hard?;)

Since you wrote an Android question I assume you know the PHP part so, otherwise it shouldn't be more than a google search away!

Comment: Uuuu I haven't searched enough so, thank you!
No at the moment I don't know the php but I'll learn it to do this. So its just a call to my php file and it will do what i've wrote inside it right?

Answer (score 0):

For the php part you should be able to find a basic walk-through by googling. For example: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html.