# Send and receive info between windows and android through wireless network

Tags: c#, android, wireless

I have a c# win app that works with SQL. I want to develop an Android app that sends a query to win app and query result return to Android app. I didn't develop any android app.

1.Is there any way that I connect to my SQL database directly?

2.How send info from android app to PC?

3.How detect android device from win app?

Comment: you need to write a WebService

Comment: how call methods of WebService from android?

Comment: here are tones of questions about your issue,calling is through a background process like implementing AsyncTask class then implmenting Restful or soap request to your WebService through URL and HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Web Services and call them from your android app. Please have a look at this link which will give you information on calling webservices in android [How to call a RESTful web service from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047194/how-to-call-restful-web-service-from-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Is there any way that I connect to my SQL database directly?
```

no there is no way to access SqlServer ... directly , you have to make a webservice to communicate with sql server.

```
2.How send info from android app to PC?
```

with that WebService and a url you can call http Post/Get in your Android App and consume the related WebService and send your data to the server and get proper data from server. for implenting such behavior here(StackOverFlow) is huge number of links that you can search for it.

```
3.How detect android device from win app?
```

if i get it right you can add google usb driver which is inside Android SDK , then Eclipse/Netbeans or other IDE's can detect your android device.