# How to make request in Android equivalent to these curl commands

Tags: java, android, python, flask, android-webservice

I've developed an API in Flask for a project in Android but I don't know how to call the service and get data back from it.

The examples that I have seen don't tell me anything about including username and passwords and data like I would do with curl.

I have tried following these but I keep getting lost:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6977616/4517985
- http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

I'm looking for the Android way of executing these curl commands:

```
curl -u miguel:python -i -X GET localhost/api/resource
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"miguel","password":"python"}' localhost/api/users
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you post what you have already tried? Even the examples you have looked at would allow others to help you more effectively.

Comment: @GregtheIncredulous I have added to the question with Links and an example of what I am trying to achieve.