# Which sdk library from Azure I should use in Android to use Media Services?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-media-services

I am working on an Android app and I am trying to upload videos on Azure's Media Services. I have been trying to find some useful information in their documentation but nothing is there for that. I have found [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-java-how-to-use) for JAVA and I am trying to add dependencies using Gradle but I have been getting errors where like class not found, class not defined, path not found etc.

```
compile ('com.microsoft.windowsazure:microsoft-windowsazure-api:0.4.6'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-jaxrs'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-xc'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-core-asl'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', module: 'jackson-mapper-asl'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', module: 'jackson-datatype-joda'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jettison', module: 'jettison'

    }
    compile ('com.microsoft.windowsazure:microsoft-azure-api-core:0.5.0')
    compile ('com.microsoft.windowsazure:microsoft-azure-api-media:0.5.0')
    compile ('com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:1.0.0@aar')
    compile ('com.microsoft.azure:azure:1.0.0')
    compile ('com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0@aar')
    compile ('com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-storage:1.0.0')
    compile ('com.microsoft.azure:azure-media:0.9.7')
```

Theses are the libraries I have used and I have used all of these `exclude` block in all `compile` blocks in my gradle file as it is giving me error of duplicate files copied. I have removed repeating exclude block from here. From the example code of JAVA, I have created following class,

```
public class MediaServiceHelper {

    private String filePath, fileIdentifier;
    private static String _filePath, _fileIdentifier;

    // Media Services account credentials configuration
    private static String mediaServiceUri = "https://media.windows.net/API/";
    private static String oAuthUri = "https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
    private static String clientId = "account";
    private static String clientSecret = "key";
    private static String scope = "urn:WindowsAzureMediaServices";
    private static MediaContract mediaService;

    // Encoder configuration
    private static String preferredEncoder = "Media Encoder Standard";
    private static String encodingPreset = "Adaptive Streaming";


    public MediaServiceHelper() {
    }

    public MediaServiceHelper(String filePath, String fileIdentifier) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.fileIdentifier = fileIdentifier;

        _filePath = filePath;
        _fileIdentifier = fileIdentifier;
    }

    public void process() {
        try {
            // Set up the MediaContract object to call into the Media Services account
            Configuration configuration = MediaConfiguration.configureWithOAuthAuthentication(
                    mediaServiceUri, oAuthUri, clientId, clientSecret, scope);
            mediaService = MediaService.create(configuration);


            // Upload a local file to an Asset
            AssetInfo uploadAsset = uploadFileAndCreateAsset(fileIdentifier);
            new ErrorPrinter("Uploaded Asset Id: " + uploadAsset.getId());


            // Transform the Asset
            AssetInfo encodedAsset = encode(uploadAsset);
            new ErrorPrinter("Encoded Asset Id: " + encodedAsset.getId());

            // Create the Streaming Origin Locator
            String url = getStreamingOriginLocator(encodedAsset);

            new ErrorPrinter("Origin Locator URL: " + url);
            new ErrorPrinter("Sample completed!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            new ErrorPrinter("Exception encountered.");
            new ErrorPrinter(e.toString());
        }

    }


    private static AssetInfo uploadFileAndCreateAsset(String fileName)
            throws Exception{

        WritableBlobContainerContract uploader;
        AssetInfo resultAsset;
        AccessPolicyInfo uploadAccessPolicy;
        LocatorInfo uploadLocator = null;

        // Create an Asset
        resultAsset = mediaService.create(Asset.create().setName(fileName).setAlternateId("altId"));
        new ErrorPrinter("Created Asset " + fileName);

        // Create an AccessPolicy that provides Write access for 15 minutes
        uploadAccessPolicy = mediaService
                .create(AccessPolicy.create("uploadAccessPolicy", 15.0, EnumSet.of(AccessPolicyPermission.WRITE)));

        // Create a Locator using the AccessPolicy and Asset
        uploadLocator = mediaService
                .create(Locator.create(uploadAccessPolicy.getId(), resultAsset.getId(), LocatorType.SAS));

        // Create the Blob Writer using the Locator
        uploader = mediaService.createBlobWriter(uploadLocator);

        File file = new File(_filePath);

        // The local file that will be uploaded to your Media Services account
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

        new ErrorPrinter("Uploading " + fileName);

        // Upload the local file to the asset
        uploader.createBlockBlob(fileName, input);

        // Inform Media Services about the uploaded files
        mediaService.action(AssetFile.createFileInfos(resultAsset.getId()));
        new ErrorPrinter("Uploaded Asset File " + fileName);

        mediaService.delete(Locator.delete(uploadLocator.getId()));
        mediaService.delete(AccessPolicy.delete(uploadAccessPolicy.getId()));

        return resultAsset;
    }

    // Create a Job that contains a Task to transform the Asset
    private static AssetInfo encode(AssetInfo assetToEncode)
            throws Exception{

        // Retrieve the list of Media Processors that match the name
        ListResult<MediaProcessorInfo> mediaProcessors = mediaService
                .list(MediaProcessor.list().set("$filter", String.format("Name eq '%s'", preferredEncoder)));

        // Use the latest version of the Media Processor
        MediaProcessorInfo mediaProcessor = null;
        for (MediaProcessorInfo info : mediaProcessors) {
            if (null == mediaProcessor || info.getVersion().compareTo(mediaProcessor.getVersion()) > 0) {
                mediaProcessor = info;
            }
        }

        new ErrorPrinter("Using Media Processor: " + mediaProcessor.getName() + " " + mediaProcessor.getVersion());

        // Create a task with the specified Media Processor
        String outputAssetName = String.format("%s as %s", assetToEncode.getName(), encodingPreset);
        String taskXml = "<taskBody><inputAsset>JobInputAsset(0)</inputAsset>"
                + "<outputAsset assetCreationOptions=\"0\"" // AssetCreationOptions.None
                + " assetName=\"" + outputAssetName + "\">JobOutputAsset(0)</outputAsset></taskBody>";

        Task.CreateBatchOperation task = Task.create(mediaProcessor.getId(), taskXml)
                .setConfiguration(encodingPreset).setName("Encoding");

        // Create the Job; this automatically schedules and runs it.
        Job.Creator jobCreator = Job.create()
                .setName(String.format("Encoding %s to %s", assetToEncode.getName(), encodingPreset))
                .addInputMediaAsset(assetToEncode.getId()).setPriority(2).addTaskCreator(task);
        JobInfo job = mediaService.create(jobCreator);

        String jobId = job.getId();
        new ErrorPrinter("Created Job with Id: " + jobId);

        // Check to see if the Job has completed
        checkJobStatus(jobId);
        // Done with the Job

        // Retrieve the output Asset
        ListResult<AssetInfo> outputAssets = mediaService.list(Asset.list(job.getOutputAssetsLink()));
        return outputAssets.get(0);
    }


    public static String getStreamingOriginLocator(AssetInfo asset) throws Exception {
        // Get the .ISM AssetFile
        ListResult<AssetFileInfo> assetFiles = mediaService.list(AssetFile.list(asset.getAssetFilesLink()));
        AssetFileInfo streamingAssetFile = null;
        for (AssetFileInfo file : assetFiles) {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".ism")) {
                streamingAssetFile = file;
                break;
            }
        }

        AccessPolicyInfo originAccessPolicy;
        LocatorInfo originLocator = null;

        // Create a 30-day readonly AccessPolicy
        double durationInMinutes = 60 * 24 * 30;
        originAccessPolicy = mediaService.create(
                AccessPolicy.create("Streaming policy", durationInMinutes, EnumSet.of(AccessPolicyPermission.READ)));

        // Create a Locator using the AccessPolicy and Asset
        originLocator = mediaService
                .create(Locator.create(originAccessPolicy.getId(), asset.getId(), LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin));

        // Create a Smooth Streaming base URL
        return originLocator.getPath() + streamingAssetFile.getName() + "/manifest";
    }

    private static void checkJobStatus(String jobId) throws Exception{
        boolean done = false;
        JobState jobState = null;
        while (!done) {
            // Sleep for 5 seconds
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            // Query the updated Job state
            jobState = mediaService.get(Job.get(jobId)).getState();
            new ErrorPrinter("Job state: " + jobState);

            if (jobState == JobState.Finished || jobState == JobState.Canceled || jobState == JobState.Error) {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me which library to use in Android so I can upload videos to Azure Media Services? Or any other reference that I can use to find solution for my problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can refer to the dependencies of the maven repository for [Azure Media service](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-media/0.9.7) to try to fix your issue, but I think @Dwyane George is right, there is not a media service sdk for Android, and the java sdk may be not compatible with Android.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage your Azure Media Services (AMS) account through either the .NET Framework SDK or Java SDK. The .NET Framework SDK provides the full range of functionality for managing AMS services. The Java SDK supports a subset of that functionality. You can get the Java SDK from Microsoft's [Java Developer Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/java/). AMS provides a handful of [code samples](https://github.com/southworkscom/azure-sdk-for-media-services-java-samples) for using the Java SDK.

If you'd like to use scenarios that are not supported in the Java SDK, you can make calls directly to the AMS REST service. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047194/how-to-call-a-restful-web-service-from-android) for more information on how to make calls to a RESTful service from Android. Cheers.